# What c++ compilers have offline documentation directly in headers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, intellisense

I installed VS Code to write programs for esp32 on c/с++. I have followed suggestion from official docs and installed msys2. Created a project exactly as it is in the official docs. Intellisence not working. https://i.stack.imgur.com/We5wR.png
From this post [Visual Studio Code Intellisense doesn't show function documentation for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73326790/visual-studio-code-intellisense-doesnt-show-function-documentation-for-c) I figured out that my gcc libs doesn't have offline documentation in headers. So why the hell it's shown in the vscode guidelines like it should work??
So is it really impossible to just switch a compiler for one that have internal documentation?

I tried [switching different tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v96Am.png), [and different intellisense modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfW3t.png) and different compiler variants which I can't show because eventualy vscode stopped indexing all suggestions for compiler files. There was something like msvc, cl.exe, gcc, cpp, mingw64 and whole lot of others. Nothing changed.
I need intellisense to show as many documentation as possible.