VS Code C++ IntelliSense not showing documentation comments
Summary of issue:
My VS Code C++ IntelliSense is only showing type information, not documentation comments, in hover tooltips.
Behavior:
When hovering over types like vector, I only see the type signature (e.g., class std::__1::vector<std::__1::string>) without the usual documentation comments/IntelliSense details that explain what the class/methods do. I'm on macOS 15.1.1 using clang++ with libc++, and using VS Code C/C++ extension version 1.22.11.

Context:
My .vscode/settings.json file:
{
    "C_Cpp.default.systemIncludePath": [
        "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1"
    ],
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "default",
    "C_Cpp.default.browse.limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": false,
    "C_Cpp.default.intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64",
    "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++17",
    "C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++",
    "C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "LLVM",
    "C_Cpp.default.mergeConfigurations": true,
    "files.associations": {
        "vector": "cpp"
    }
}

My c_cpp_properties.json file:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/16/include",
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-stdlib=libc++"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}


You've described a bunch of stuff that your IDE doesn't do (that I think you want it to do), but you have not actually asked a question.   Also; please don't post pictures of text - just post plain text.

First thing to check: Make absolutely certain that the header actually does contain comments in the format VS Code's Intellisense module expects.

@JesperJuhl "please don't post pictures of text" -- The picture in this question is of the hover tooltip. The text is secondary in this case. (OP: It is hard to tell what one should focus on in the image. A little image editing to add arrows or something to draw attention to the tiny, subtle tooltip might be an improvement.)

I suspect the answer to be the same as for https://stackoverflow.com/a/73366580/11107541, although that is about msvc and this is about xcode. let me know if that's the case

@starball -- yes, I think the problem is the same. I'm going to try libstdc++. I tried that extension mentioned in the linked comment and that didn't solve my issue.
